# How do I create a list of user inputs?

Tags: java

I am coding in Java and I have to create a program that accepts user input, which I have done. But I am confused as to what statement I can use to list those integer input by the user.

This is what I have so far:

```
//Biker's Journey Program

import java.util.Scanner;
public class lab2
{
public static void main( String[] args )
{   
    Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in);
    int w;
    int x;
    int y;
    int z;
    int result;

    System.out.print("Please enter the first day's traveled miles: ");
    w = input.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Please enter the second day's traveled miles: ");
    x = input.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Please enter the third day's traveled miles: ");
    y = input.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Please enter the last day's traveled miles: ");
    z = input.nextInt();

    System.out.print("The number of miles traveled was: "); 

    System.out.println()

    result = (w + x + y + z) / 4;

    System.out.printf("The average miles per day traveled is %d\n", result);
}   
}
```

And this segment of code does the computing, I just can not figure out how to get the integers listed like this this picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xcIq5.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
System.out.printf("The number of miles traveled each day was: %d %d %d %d", w,x,y,z);
```

Comment: ok, so if it' good, perhaps you can mark this as the solution?